# How to apply separate filters for every page

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I am new to powerbi embedding and I want to apply separate filters for each page that I have in my report
[image]

for e.g. I want some filters specifically for this page
and I have three pages in my report
[image]
I am able to apply filter but it is reflecting to all pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Page` level filters which will add filters for the report page you specify.

Please follow the below code snippets:

Create separate `filter` objects for each page like below:

```js
const filter1 = {
    $schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
    target: {
        table: "table_name",
        column: "column_name"
    },
    operator: "operator",
    values: ["values"]
};
```

Retrieve the `page` collection of your report:

```js
const pages = await report.getPages();
```

Use page indexing to get the particular page and use `updateFilters()` to add / update / remove `filters`:

```js
await pages[1].updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Add, [filter1]);
```

Similarly, you can do for each of your report pages:

Please refer:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/get-visuals#how-to-get-a-list-of-pages
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters